# Фантомный баг не дает уснуть. Как пофиксить?

Tags: javascript

Разработал я значит кастомный таймер, на основе кукисов, у себя на локалке. Таймер обратного отсчета еще и цену покупки меняет(изменяет value скрытого input-а c ценой в форме оформления заказа в зависимости от того, сколько времени осталось):

```html
<!-- ===========================форма НАЧАЛО=================== -->
<form class="form-maraphon" method="GET" action="/marathon/integrations/handlers.php">

  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-maraphon-input" placeholder="Имя" required="">
  <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-maraphon-input" placeholder="Телефон" required="">
  <input type="email" name="email" class="form-maraphon-input" placeholder="Email" required="">
  <input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="150">

  <button class="form-maraphon-btn" type="submit">Перейти к оплате и забрать подарок</button>

</form>

<style>
  .form-maraphon-input {
    margin-top: 10px;
    min-width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #F6F7FE;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9BB3E8;
    color: #A3A3A4;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  
  .form-maraphon-btn {
    background: linear-gradient(93.78deg, #12C0BC 8.38%, #0ED12E 80.53%);
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    min-width: 190px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9BB3E8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
</style>
<!-- ===========================форма КОНЕЦ==================== -->

<script src="https://unpkg.com/cookielib/src/cookie.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/moment_js/moment.js"></script>
<script>
  function changePrice(time_start) {

    time_start2 = moment(time_start); //переведем в удобный формат
    now = moment(); //текущий момент времени
    console.log('time_start2: ', time_start2);
    console.log('now: ', now);
    let time1 = time_start2.clone().add(2, 'hours');
    let time2 = time_start2.clone().add(2, 'days');
    let time3 = time_start2.clone().add(4, 'days');

    let price1 = '350';
    let price2 = '650';
    let price3 = '2420';

    if (now.isAfter(time1) && now.isBefore(time2)) {
      document.getElementById('price').value = price1;
      console.log('активирован price1');
    }

    if (now.isAfter(time2) && now.isBefore(time3)) {
      document.getElementById('price').value = price2;
      console.log('активирован price2');
    }

    if (now.isAfter(time3)) {
      document.getElementById('price').value = price3;
      console.log('активирован price3');
    }

  }


  function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {

    var t = endtime + 48 * 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000 - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return {
      'total': t,
      'days': days,
      'hours': hours,
      'minutes': minutes,
      'seconds': seconds
    };

  }


  function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
    var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
    var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
    var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

    function updateClock() {
      var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

      daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
      hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
      minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
      secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

      if (t.total <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timeinterval);
      }
    }
    updateClock();
    var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    changePrice(endtime);
  }


  //установим текущее клиентское время в куку, если значения нет
  if (getCookie('timeFirst') == null) {
    setCookie('timeFirst', String(Date.parse(new Date())), {
      expires: Date(14)
    });
  }

  var timeFirst = Number(getCookie('timeFirst'));
  console.log("timeFirst: ", timeFirst);
  initializeClock('countdown', timeFirst);
</script>

<style>
  .countdown {
    color: #bold;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 32px;
  }
  
  .countdown-number {
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .countdown-time {
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #008116a;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .countdown-text {
    display: block;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
  }
</style>
```

Затем начал интегрировать код на уже готовую страницу на боевом сайте:
https://denisdemidov.com/marathon/

При интеграции ловлю визуальный баг - скачет шапка с таймером, который я разработал, а в таймере время от времени отображается NaN вместо значений...в чем проблема? Единственное что менял при интеграции - пути подключения скриптов и одно свойство css, чтобы сменить цвет таймера.

Comment: Ну скачет из-за того, что когда вставляется NAN у тебя не влазит по ширине. Открой в инспекторе `div` в котором у тебя время, он имеет жесткую ширину 25% (как и его соседи). Отключи — увидишь что скакать перестанет. А вот почему у тебя NAN там приходит — ну расставь `console.log` там побольше и поймёшь. Если не получится — сделай тут нормальный пример, который бы работал, посмотрим.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Были дубликаты кода при интеграции, проблема решена.